# Automate Series creation in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate a simple task on Excel but I can't figure out how to do it. (I tried the macro recorder but it didn't help...)

Let's assume I have a fixed space A1:T40
All the cells in this space are either blank or contain the number 0.

I want to select all zeros (=non-empty cells) and add them to a serie called "zeros".

How can I automate this step using a macro?

Manually, I would use Ctrl+G > Special > Constants > OK to select those cells, click Formulas > Define Name > enter the name "zeros" and hit ok.

Comment: How did the macro recorder not help? What was the code it generated when you recorded those steps?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DefineNameForZeroes()
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
        Name:="Zeroes", _
        RefersTo:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("Zeroes").Comment = "All the zeroes on this sheet"
End Sub
```